# How to add margin comments in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, marginpar

I use Beamer for my presentations and I would like to know how I could add some text in the two sides of an inserted figure using `\includegraphics[scale=]{}`
and `\caption{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `columns` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Image with comments}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.2\textwidth}
    Left comment

    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption{Example image}
    \end{figure}

    \column{.2\textwidth}
    Right comment
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```